# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Issues with using environment variable to control stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use both `branch_name` as well as an `env` variable to enable and disable tests in the pipeline. The `env` controls the tests being triggered. However, even though the expression conditions meet my pipeline doesn't trigger the expected test.

```
environment {
    sanity_tests_enabled = true
    smoke_tests_enabled = false
}
stages {
    stage('Build') { 
        steps {
            sh 'npm install --force'
            sh 'ng build'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') { 
        parallel {
            stage('Sanity Tests') {
                when {
                    allOf {
                        expression{env.sanity_tests_enabled = true}
                        anyOf {
                            branch 'PR-*'
                            branch 'dev'
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`env.sanity_tests_enabled = true` is an assignment not a comparision. You are comparing boolean values by using `==` . I also think you are missing a `;` in your `anyOf`.

```
when {
  allOf {
    expression{env.sanity_tests_enabled == true}
    anyOf {
      branch 'PR-*';
      branch 'dev'
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried `expression{env.sanity_tests_enabled == true}` but It still doesn't trigger the stage. Is your additional indent under expression intentional? I have expression and anyOf on the same indentation.

Comment: The indentation shouldn't have an impact on the logic of the script. Can you debug what exactly isnt working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also try like this

1. Declare the boolean globally before the pipeline

`boolean sanity_tests_enabled = true`

```
when {
    expression { return ((!sanity_tests_enabled) && (branch 'your branch name')) }
  }
```